# Is it possible to send my application's JSON log output to Cloudwatch using awslogs agent?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a python application (dockerised) which output's logs in JSON format.
I'd like to send these logs to Cloudwatch. To avoid making any code changes i was hoping to use the awslogs Cloudwatch agent to sync the log file to Cloudwatch, but after looking at the Cloudwatch agent's timestamp format field 'timestamp_format', it's expecting my application to output the timestamp in a format like:

```
datetime_format = %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S UTC
```

But my application logs the timestamp as JSON value, e.g:

```
{"log":"{\"levelname\": \"INFO\", \"message\": \"example log\", \"filename\": \"application.py\", "time":"2022-05-16T11:36:03.04390948Z"}
```

Is it possible for me to send these logs to Cloudwatch using the agent? If not, what would be the best alternative?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can update the `timestamp_format` field to match your logs by updating the [configuration file for the CloudWatch Agent.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html#CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Logssection)

From your JSON field, your timestamp format should look like this in your CloudWatch Agent's config file (named `config.json` by default):

```
{
    "logs": {
        "logs_collected": {
            "files": {
                "collect_list": [
                    {
                        "file_path": "/path/to/logfile.log",
                        "log_group_name": "log_group",
                        "log_stream_name": "log_stream",
                        "timezone": "UTC",
                        "timestamp_format": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the AWS documentation, the `%f` formatter for fractional seconds matches from one to nine digits. I've successfully sent logs via the CloudWatch Agent with this `timestamp_format` for timestamps in JSON logs with three-digit and nine-digit fractional second precision.

Note that if you don't specify the `timezone` as `UTC`, then the value will default to `Local` - beware of daylight savings!